# How to return LINQ query to View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have the following Action in my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult List() {
        ViewBag.Title = "View Current Stores";
        var curStores = 
            (from store in stores.Stores 
            where store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID 
            select store).ToList();
        return View(curStores);
    }
```

Which is suppose to get a list of stores and render it as a table in view.  However the LINQ statement is throwing the following error:

```
Non-static method requires a target.
```

What should I do?

Comment: It could happen because `curCompany` is null

Comment: is curCompany populated in Controller constructor? can you share that code?

Comment: Yup curCompany was null.  I am new to MVC, so I haven't really figure out how to load data yet under this environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `stores.Stores.Where(o=>o.CompanyID==curCompany.ID).ToList()`; but make sure that other variables used but not defined inside the actions (i.e. curCompany and stores) are valid one.